# Pandas, truncate a string that is too long in a column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working various columns in a csv file with pandas and jupyter notebook I would need  to truncate a string that is too long in a column eg:

```
test_column
abcde 1234 free foo row saw hello number ok by test
free foo row saw 1234 hello test
.....
```

I would like the rest to be truncated in the column after 15 characters:

```
test_column
abcde 1234 free  //---->after 15 charter
free foo row sa //---->after 15 charter
```

.....
i'm trying with

```
df = df[df['test_column'].map(lambda x: len(str(x)) < 15)]
df
```

but unfortunately I delete the whole rows longer than 15 instead of truncating it!
how could i solve it ?

thanks ?

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
res = df["test_column"].str[:15]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    abcde 1234 free
1    free foo row sa
Name: test_column, dtype: object
```

As an alternative use [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas-series-str-slice):

```
res = df["test_column"].str.slice(stop=15)
```

**Output**

```
0    abcde 1234 free
1    free foo row sa
Name: test_column, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks quick and kind, it seems to work! but recalling the columns gives me this error: "We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in" and to follow the items in the column! What happen?

Comment: What do you mean by recalling the columns?

Comment: df=df[["test_one","test_two","test_column"]]
df    maybe I forgot to tell you that I have a lot of rows

Comment: Sorry, but with the info given I cannot help

Comment: However the syntax works correctly! Probably the problem is that I have a large amount of data ... in the meantime, thanks!